# Angular Material 2 Autocomplete, mat-option element doesn't trigger keyup event

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular-material, keyup

I am looking for a way to figure out when an `mat-option` inside the `mat-autocomplete` was either clicked or was selected using the enter key.

The `click` event binding works as expected but the `keyup.enter` or even just the `keyup` event doesn't work.

Is this a bug in the library or I am doing something wrong?

```
<mat-option (click)="onEnter()" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()" *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
```

Here's a live example - https://angular-3okq5u.stackblitz.io

Update: Please mention if there's a better way to handle the selection of an option at the `<mat-option>` element level.

Comment: can you share your code in online ide??

Comment: Best way I have found is not to use Angular Material and instead just use HTML and Angular. <div class="use-angular-material-css-here" (keyup.enter)="worksEveryTime('YES')">
Plus you can still get the visual interaction with matRipple

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use onSelectionChange event in options if you want to trigger a function on option change. it will also trigger if you use keyboard to select the auto-complete option which you are trying to achieve here.

```
<input (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event)" matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option  (onSelectionChange)="onEnter($event)" (click)="onEnter()"  *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

**Update**

onSelectionChange event is triggering twice whenever you change the option and it's because of the [existing issue in Angular material](https://www.github.com/angular/material2/issues/4094). Work around for the issue is also given that you should check the event before doing anything inside the function.

```
 onEnter(evt: any){
    if (evt.source.selected) {
    alert("hello ");
    }
  }
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete)

Comment: I want the event to come from the option and not the input. My expectation is that the way click is working, the `keyup.enter` on the option should also work.

Comment: use onSelectionChange event if you want to trigger a function on change which you want to do I guess. <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onEnter(val)" *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">

Comment: onSelectionChange fires twice for an option change if you check except for the first one. the `isUserInput` property in the event is true at first and then it becomes false. Which seems confusing to me

Comment: I could certainly check for `isUserInput` being true and only then make my changes but that wouldn't that be a bad approach?

Comment: This is a already existing issue in angular material and they have gave workaround too. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4094. check events before doing anything inside the function  onEnter(evt:any){if (evt.source.selected) {alert("hello "); } } you can check the working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete

Comment: Thanks so much! :) That's what I wanted! Can you please update the same in your answer too so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```html
<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="choose(item)" 
            *ngFor="let item of keyWord" value="{{item}}"> {{item}} </mat-option>
```

Answer (score 1):

**autoActiveFirstOption**

Using the `autoActiveFirstOption` directive it is possible to trigger the `optionSelected` event with the enter key. This is exactly the behaviour I wanted when trying to register the enter key event.

```
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption (optionSelected)='setSearchValue($event.option.value)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that instead of handling click or keyup.enter (which was not working)  events on the mat-option element, we can just simply listen to selectionChange on the mat-select element itself. That way the keyboard enter press event is fired properly. And then access the value selected on the callback like this:

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption" (selectionChange)="setOption($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value" [attr.arialabel]="option.value">
      {{ lang.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

And then, handle it like:

```
setOption(optionChangedEvent: MatSelectChange) {
   console.log(optionChangedEvent.value);
   [rest of logic goes here]
}
```